# High CPU Usage Issue on Magento Website hosted in EC2 with MySQL Aurora RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm encountering recurrent high CPU usage problems with my Magento website hosted on an EC2 instance, paired with a MySQL Aurora RDS database. Despite enabling slow query logs, I'm still unable to pinpoint the root cause effectively due to the required development efforts. Additionally, the database holds a substantial size of 284GB, primarily due to a specific table storing exception logs, accounting for 195GB. Importantly, no active queries are executed on this table.

Please note that the infrastructure has been procured by someone else, and unfortunately, I do not have direct access to the EC2 instances as they are located within private subnets. I would prefer to maintain this setup if possible.

Could this massive table size, specifically the 195GB exception logs table, be a potential cause of the performance impact I'm experiencing? Any insights or suggestions would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input.